# "Gtk Warning: Theme parsing error" for no-longer-installed extension

Tags: gnome, gtk, gnome-shell-extension, 18.10

I long ago uninstalled the GNOME Extension `no-title-bar`, but I still get errors launching Gtk apps:

```
(yad:548): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:05:20.038: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1:112: Failed to import: Error opening file /home/cat/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/no-title-bar@franglais125.gmail.com/stylesheet.css: No such file or directory

(yad:548): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:05:20.038: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:2:118: Failed to import: Error opening file /home/cat/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/no-title-bar@franglais125.gmail.com/stylesheet-tiled.css: No such file or directory
```

The directory `.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/no-title-bar` does not even exist, which is why there is a problem. But how do I clean up the warning? The extension has left behind some artifacts?

Comment: warnings are not for you to fix but for the maintainers ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind the extension doesn't work on shell 3.30 anyway, so i would have to wait for it to be updated, re-install it, and uninstall it again -- no point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Likely the file `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` contains `@import url(filename)` statements, referring to non-existent files in `.../extensions/no-title-bar`.

Remove the erroneous import statements from the file `gtk.css`.

If `no-title-bar` is still registered as installed:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions | grep --color no-title-bar && echo installed
```

You can remove its entry from the array `org.gnome.shell.enabled-extensions` in `dconf-editor` (`apt install dconf-editor`) by browsing to `org`, then `gnome`, then `shell`, etc.

There also might remain its entry in `org.gnome.shell.extensions`. Remove all its sub-keys and the entry `org.gnome.shell.extensions.no-title-bar` will be removed as well.

[Github](https://github.com/franglais125/no-title-bar/issues/73) [Forum post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=236970)

> **OOO**:
>
> You can check enabled extensions with:
>
> ```
> gsettings get org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions
> ```
>
> If no-title-bar extension is listed, remove it from the array with gsettings or dconf-editor.
>
> **enbQao**:
>
> ...there was still an entry there for that extension. I removed that entry and all other entries I could find... this did not solve the warning. It still shows.
>
> **enbQao**:
>
> The warning was due to a import statement from `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`
> Removing these statements and the warning will not show up anymore.

Comment: Exactly. Happens with Firefox now

Answer (score 1):

**on 20.04**, after upgrading from 18.04

this **problem re-surfaced** for me recently

## my cause & solution:

- there was a snap package installed, `gtk-themes-common` (I think), which contained Yaru theme files
- it *clashed* with the system installed gtk-theme Yaru
- *removal of the snap* solved my problems